# How to call a HashSet method in separate main class

Tags: java, set, hashset

I'm trying to do a Java problem that's noted in the textbook "Building Java Programs" 4th Ed. The problem is number 11 in Chapter 11, Page 751:

Write a method called symmetricSetDifference that accepts two sets as parameters and returns a new Set containing their symmetric difference(that is, the set of elements contained in either of the two sets, but not in both) For an example: The difference between the sets[1,4,7,9] and [2,4,5,6,7] is [1,2,5,6,9].

The symmetricSetDifference method:

```
public static Set<Integer>symmetricSetDifference(Set<Integer>list1, Set<Integer>list2) {
        Set<Integer>set1 = new HashSet<>();
        set1.add(1);
        set1.add(4);
        set1.add(7);
        set1.add(9);

        Set<Integer>set2 = new HashSet<>();
        set2.add(2);
        set2.add(4);
        set2.add(5);
        set2.add(6);
        set2.add(7);

        Set<Integer>diff = new HashSet<>(set1);
        diff.addAll(set2);
        Set<Integer>curr = new HashSet<>(set1);
        curr.retainAll(set2);
        diff.removeAll(curr);

        System.out.println(diff);
        return diff;

    }
```

This is the main class. It's in a separate file:

```
public class TestPointClass {
    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

       newSet = MyUtils.symmetricSetDifference(List1, List2);
}
```

The problem is that I get an "illegal expression" error along with a series of "cannot find the identifier errors. I was wondering if anyone has any pointers on what I can do? (I've checked for any duplicate issues and could not find anything similar, thus apologies in advance if there were)

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html. You're not understanding what method arguments are, apparently. Read the tutorial I linked to.

Comment: Ensure that you're actually passing in `Set` as opposed to `List`. Also, posting the stacktrace is helpful when asking for help.

Comment: Check. I've changed the method line to public static Set<Integer>symmetricSetDifference(Set<Integer>set1, Set<Integer>set2) and remove the two hashSet calls, but I still can't call the method in the main class.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable newSet
  location: class lab6.TestPointClass
 at lab6.TestPointClass.main(TestPointClass.java:59)
/Users/GeraldShields/Library/Caches/NetBeans/8.2/executor-snippets/run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 16 seconds)

Comment: @JavaNewbie in the main method you're sending 2 arguments to your method but where are those declared, initialized? Also, in the `symmetricSetDifference` you'll need spaces after each and every arguments.

Comment: Also, you're trying to run code that doesn't even compile. Don't do that. Read and fix the errors listed by the compiler. All of them. And then, and only then, running the program starts making sense.

Comment: I've assumed the arguments would be declared and initialized in main. The symmetricSetDifference method used to be a class with its own contained main class, thus I'm trying to recast it as a method in which I send arguments to and then get the result.

Comment: You're essentially creating new Sets which have nothing to do with the arguments so the arguments are basically pointless.

Comment: JB Nizet no problem with that. However, even after I've made the changes (as per your input), the program still errors at the newSet line in main. The method isn't having any issues and when I tried to debug, the error happens at the newSet line in main.

Comment: @JavaNewbie I haven't suggested any change. I suggested you take a step back, and learn what method arguments are for, by reading a tutorial or a book. My suggestion still stands. It's way too early for you to deal with collections and generics: you don't understand variables, methods and arguments yet. Learn the basics first.

Answer (score 0):

do the setup of your both Sets (set1,set2) outside the method and add them as parameter:

```
 Set<Integer>set1 = new HashSet<>();
    set1.add(1);
    ...

    Set<Integer>set2 = new HashSet<>();
    set2.add(2);
    ...

   MyUtils.symmetricSetDifference(set1 , set2 );
```

if you want to use the return type you have to do it like that:

```
Set<Integer> result = MyUtils.symmetricSetDifference(set1 , set2 );
```

Comment: JB Nizet and, IEE1394  linuxNoob Thank you guys(or gal if one of you was). Your'e right. I was doing the sets in the method instead of main. Once I did that and double-checked the method call and the method arguments themselves, it worked. Again Thank you for dealing with Newbie scrum such of I.